# Is it possible to forward all emails from a contact in Gmail if said contact has multiple email addresses? If so, how?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

My flatmate and I recently signed up for a shared T-Mobile plan because it was cheaper than having separate ones. I am the main account holder so all of the bills and stuff go to my email address. Now, my flatmate wants me to forward all copies of the email I get over to him so he'll have records of everything as well as knowing how much he'd have to pay for his line.

My problem is that T-Mobile, like many companies, sends different emails from many different email addresses. I have all of the addresses listed under one contact in Gmail and I was wondering if it'd be possible to set up a filter to forward all messages from every email address in that contact all over to my flatmate. I know I can send them all over in different filters, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it in just one. I use filters a lot and I'd prefer if there wasn't 50 or so different ones that did the same thing.

Comment: Seems it would be simpler to use the GMail alias capability to provide a unique email address. If you're `joe@gmail.com`, have your account info go to `joe+account@gmail.com`, then use a filter based on the TO address.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, but you can use the `OR` operator to have multiple `from:` addresses in a single filter rather than having a filter for each separate address.

Just put your string in the "Has the words" field when you create your filter.

```
from:billing@example.com OR from:customerservice@example.net OR go-away@example.org
```